# Selecting records where autoincrement ID is bigger, but date column is in the past

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag, self-join, lead

I have a table with two columns. First one is an autoincrement `ID` column, second one is a `datetime` column where next data should be in future to the previous. I need to select values where it is not true.

Example:

| ID | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-10 |
| 2 | 2022-10-11 |
| 3 | 2022-10-12 |
| 4 | 2022-10-13 |
| 5 | 2022-08-01 |
| 6 | 2022-08-02 |
| 7 | 2022-08-03 |
| 8 | 2022-10-14 |
| 9 | 2022-10-15 |

I want to select only those rows, where previous dates is in future to them.

So from example above, my result should be rows 5,6,7.

I tried to do that with self-joins, and LAG/LEAD functions, but in that case I should know a quantity of this rows. In my case it can be any number of lines which don't fit into pattern

update.: table is very big(~5m records), so can't self join with '>'/'<' operators because it is not executing in time

Comment: If you have 5 million rows then you clearly don't have five million distinct dates. I'm interested in this problem but please post more representative data. Index info would also be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the self-JOIN and inequality conditional expressions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t0.*
FROM [table] t0
INNER JOIN [table] t1 ON t1.ID < t0.ID AND t1.TimeStamp > t0.TimeStamp
```

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for hint. Logically I think it would be fine, problem is that my table very large(~5m records) and it was running 20 minutes before I cancel it

Comment: Then probably you need to add an index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MAX instead:

```sql
select *
from (
    select *, max(timestamp) over(order by id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as maxVal
    from (
        VALUES  (1, N'2022-10-10')
        ,   (2, N'2022-10-11')
        ,   (3, N'2022-10-12')
        ,   (4, N'2022-10-13')
        ,   (5, N'2022-08-01')
        ,   (6, N'2022-08-02')
        ,   (7, N'2022-08-03')
        ,   (8, N'2022-10-14')
        ,   (9, N'2022-10-15')
    ) t (ID,TimeStamp)
) x
where x.maxVal > x.TimeStamp
```

This checks so no previous IDs are higher than the current ID and outputs:

| ID | TimeStamp | maxVal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2022-08-01 | 2022-10-13 |
| 6 | 2022-08-02 | 2022-10-13 |
| 7 | 2022-08-03 | 2022-10-13 |

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, i never learn :D but of course, since we have no duplicates here, ROWS are better

Comment: Difference in results is only if there are duplicates in the ordering, otherwise it's only a performance benefit.

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions like this it is helpful to provide the DDL/DML. Using your example data:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, TimeStamp DATE);

INSERT INTO @Table (TimeStamp) VALUES
('2022-10-10'), ('2022-10-11'), ('2022-10-12'), ('2022-10-13'),
('2022-08-01'), ('2022-08-02'), ('2022-08-03'), ('2022-10-14'),
('2022-10-15');
```

Using this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT ID, TimeStamp, MAX(TimeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS mTimeStamp
          FROM @Table
       ) a
 WHERE TimeStamp < mTimeStamp;
```

| ID | TimeStamp | mTimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2022-08-01 | 2022-10-13 |
| 6 | 2022-08-02 | 2022-10-13 |
| 7 | 2022-08-03 | 2022-10-13 |

Here we're using a windowed function `MAX` to find the largest date ordered by the `ID` column. Using an outer query we can then compare the `TimeStamp` to this `MAX` value and determine if the current row is less than the windowed maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Check for existence of an "earlier" row with a later date:

```
select * from T t1
where exists (
    select 1 from T t2
    where t2.id < t1.id and t2."timestamp" > t1."timestamp"
);
```

Your data would suggest that dates are unique but it's not clear you've described the most general problem.